# Make prediction after finished training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
I've made simple prediction model with keras and bag of words based on the code which I found in the tutorials. Loading dataset and training finished without problem and accuracy is around 88%.
Dataset has two columns text and tag (i.e. "some text, a"). How can I test trained model with some other data which is not in dataset like model.predict(some text)?
```

This is sample dataset:
tekst,tag
Sconto,n
Trg Vinodolskog zakona 5,a
I wish to save the model so I don't have to train it every time I run the script. Is correct way to put at the end of the script "model.save('my_model.h5')"?
How can I the load the model and make prediction with data that it's not in dataset?

```
import logging
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
import gensim
import nltk
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


df = pd.read_csv('dataset3.csv')
df = df[pd.notnull(df['tag'])]
df.head(10)

def print_plot(index):
    example = df[df.index == index][['tekst', 'tag']].values[0]
    if len(example) > 0:
        print(example[0])
        print('Tag:', example[1])
print_plot(0)
REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE = re.compile('[/(){}\[\]\|@,;]')
BAD_SYMBOLS_RE = re.compile('[^0-9a-z #+_]')
STOPWORDS = set(stopwords.words('english'))

def clean_text(text):
    """
        text: a string

        return: modified initial string
    """
    text = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml").text # HTML decoding
    text = text.lower() # lowercase text
    text = REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE.sub(' ', text) # replace REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE symbols by space in text
    text = BAD_SYMBOLS_RE.sub('', text) # delete symbols which are in BAD_SYMBOLS_RE from text
    text = ' '.join(word for word in text.split() if word not in STOPWORDS) # delete stopwors from text
    return text
df['tekst'] = df['tekst'].apply(clean_text)
print_plot(0)
import itertools
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.preprocessing import text, sequence
from keras import utils          
train_size = int(len(df) * .7)
print ("Train size: %d" % train_size)
print ("Test size: %d" % (len(df) - train_size))
train_posts = df['tekst'][:train_size]
train_tags = df['tag'][:train_size]

test_posts = df['tekst'][train_size:]
test_tags = df['tag'][train_size:]
max_words = 1000
tokenize = text.Tokenizer(num_words=max_words, char_level=False)
tokenize.fit_on_texts(train_posts) # only fit on train
x_train = tokenize.texts_to_matrix(train_posts)
x_test = tokenize.texts_to_matrix(test_posts)
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(train_tags)
y_train = encoder.transform(train_tags)
y_test = encoder.transform(test_tags)
num_classes = np.max(y_train) + 1
y_train = utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print('x_test shape:', x_test.shape)
print('y_train shape:', y_train.shape)
print('y_test shape:', y_test.shape)
batch_size = 32
epochs = 2
# Build the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(max_words,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    epochs=epochs,
                    verbose=1,
                    validation_split=0.1)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test,
                       batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, according to the [Keras Documentation FAQ page](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model). You just type: `model.save(filepath)`.
In case you want to load an already existing model, go with:  `keras.models.load_model(filepath)`.

Comment: Thanks! And how can I predict something? I'ce tried model.predict("text") and model.fit("text") but this gives me errors.

Comment: The `predict` syntax is as follows: `predict(x, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None)`, where x is the input data. If you input a string you get error in return. You can ind more information [here](https://keras.io/models/sequential/#predict) .

Comment: I need to do this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43483954/keras-predict-with-word-embeddings-back-to-string

Comment: I'm still having problem with prediction. I need to input string to predict syntax so I can retrieve tag of that word or sentence. I've tried with texts_to_matrix but with no effect

Answer (score 2):

Once you have finished training your model, you can save the weights to disk by using `model.save_weights(path)`.

You can then load the weights into a model of the *same architecture* using `model.load_weights(path)`.

If you also want to save the model architecture, you can use the more general `model.save(path)` which will save

1. The model weights,
2. The model architecture,
3. The optimizer states.

You can then load the model using

```
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model(path)
```

After you have recovered the model and its weight, you can then `evaluate` the model to determine its accuracy or do `predictions` on new data using

```
prediction = model.predict(x_test)

loss, metrics = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

Comment: Thank you and Leevo also and have a Happy New Year.

Comment: I wrote this but now instead of predicting which tag is string as it is in dataset ('string','tag') it's predicting every character in string and it is wrong.   
`encoder = LabelEncoder() 
encoder = encoder.fit(test_tags)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(test_tags)
dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)
string = 'iban:24900024545454'
query = tokenize.texts_to_matrix(string)
prediction = model.predict_classes(query)
label = encoder.inverse_transform(prediction)
print(label)`   result: ['n' 'a' 'n' 'n' 'n' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'n' 'n' 'n' 'a' 
 'a'] it should be like this [a] or [n] or....